# Precision of reciprocal in floating point arithmetics

Tags: math, precision

For fun, I'm trying to implement Chudnovsky algorithm to calculate pi in java using an arbitrary precision floating point library. One thing that strikes me is that I need to calculate the reciprocal of a number 1/n, since the formula is described as 1/pi = sum(...)

How many significant digits/digits of precision would one need of the floating point number n, in order for 1/n to have a desired precision? Is there an easy answer to this? I tried doing some calculations like 1/0.100009999999 = 9.99900010009 to determine the reciprocal of 0.1 with five correct digits after the decimal point. I see that if I take the first three digits after the decimal point, and round the result I get the correct value 10, but is there a general rule for how many digits are correct after the 1/n operation? I am also interested in the same result but in binary and hexadecimal bases.

Tried googling and fast search on Stackoverflow, but didnt find any previous answer to this. Apologies if duplicate exists.

Comment: For pi (as it is between 1 and 10), it should be within range of one digit. So to get thousand digits precision, you will need up to 1001 digits precision on reciprocal. Do you need to know exactly? You are getting estimated value anyway around the end of precision, so one digit here or there hardly matters? I hope you are not testing anything of that using built-in double/float values in any language...

Comment: Thank you for your input. What would be a general answer for a number n that is not pi (as pi is not between 1 and 10 in base 2)?
No, I don't use built in double/float. I will use either Java's built-in BigDecimal, or apfloat

Answer (score 2):

You want to compute 1/x, but are computing 1/(x+d) with d=delta x the truncation error. By binomial theorems,

```
1/(x+d) = (x-d)/(x²-d²)
```

and since we can assume that d² is far below any floating point error, the error of the reciprocal is -d/x² and the more relevant relative error is -d/x.

Which confirms the comment of Artur Biesiadowski, if 1/x is between 1 and 10, then the error magnification is by a factor 10 in the worst case.